# How to import or call big data in Compaq Visual Fortran 6.5

Tags: fortran

I have problem how to import very big matrix to fortran 6.5. For example, my .for file matrix is very big 120 MB and matrix is given in the form

```
  A(1,1)=691627.009959795*x(1)**2 - 3428.41117804251*x(1)*x(2) -
 # 156.91392014999*x(2)**2 + 428391.21915942*x(1)*x(3) - 953.4687530
 #88931*x(2)*x(3) + 66317.7918091961*x(3)**2 + 159956.172489745*x(1)
 #*x(4) - 427.609460294073*x(2)*x(4) + 49548.6129072796*x(3)*x(4) + 
 #9246.97185672321615*x(4)**2 - 34020.3929685886*x(1)*x(5) + 23.9104
 #515534*x(2)*x(5) - 10515.7437145023*x(3)*x(5) - 3939.86670772623

  A(1,2)=433427.009959795*x(1)**2 - 3444.41117804251*x(1)*x(2) -
 # 144.91392014999*x(2)**2 + 455391.21915942*x(1)*x(3) - 955.4687530
 #58931*x(2)*x(3) + 66317.7918091961*x(3)**2 + 159956.172489745*x(1)
 #*x(4) - 457.609460294073*x(2)*x(4) + 49548.6129072796*x(3)*x(4) + 
 #3246.97182321615*x(4)**2 - 14020.3929685886*x(1)*x(5) + 23.9104019
 #515534*x(2)*x(5) - 14515.7437145023*x(3)*x(5) - 3669.86670772623
 ...
```

as the matrix is very big, I can copy/paste in fortran sheet just small part of matrix of 1 MB, so in that case I must devide 120MB on 120 parts and copy/paste in fortran sheet with summation of all parts. How to call or import matrix from fortran in this full form?

Comment: Are you trying to put data inside the code? You should write a code that reads your matrix data from a file, and then do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @IRO-bot did you try to call matrix with big size, in compaq version? can you put some example?

Comment: No, I never used Compaq Fortran compiler. Just write standard Fortran, and you will be fine, regardless of the compiler (in most cases, at least). This question needs serious editting. It is very cryptic in its current form. Can you please be more specific about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I used CVF, found it to be a fine compiler (albeit a more recent version - 6.6c). I cannot understand what are you asking. Are you saying you have a .for file of 120Mb full of terms like the above?! Please elaborate on the question, and give more clear explanation of what you have and what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: @ldigas yes I have .for file of 120Mb full of terms like above and I need to compile and use for further calculation in visual compaq 6.5.

Comment: @Pipe - And compiler is okey with that (a 120Mb source file)? Just asking. In any case, if I understood correctly, you're asking how to handle a file of that size? All you need is an editor that will be able to open a text file of that magnitude (vim can do it, for example) together with maybe fortran highlighting (although I advice turning it off with a 120mb file).

Comment: @ldigas I didn´t try yet to handle. Until now, I had matrices with size of 10 MB, so, I made parts of this matrix and then did summ. With matrix of 120 Mb I can not make 120 parts, because fortran accepted 1,2 MB matrix, and I am asking what to do? Can I just call matrix from my.for file? I need simple example.

Comment: @Pipe - How did you generate those "equations"? The thing is, source files are not really supposed to be that! large, and it is not the best practice to keep data in them if it can be avoided. Some amount of data cannot be avoided, but that is not usually in the 120mb range. Can you separate it somehow so we can try to place it in a separate file from the program itself? What are those x(1) x(2) ... terms and are they variable?

Comment: @ldigas x(1)x(2) terms are variable and it is very possible to matrix be like that. Problem is in generating, I am doing it in Maple or Matlab and I don´t want to generate it in fortran. I just want to know is it possible to call file with this size from somewhere, not to copy/paste it in worksheet. If I can do that, I will wait for compiling.

Comment: @Pipe - You can include such a file in your .for file with INCLUDE sometimes, if your compiler supports it. But it is a matter whether the compiler will accept a 120mb source file. Anyway, try it. What worksheet are you talking about?

Comment: please don't call this 'matrix', this is confusing -- it's generated code. The right way is to save the coefficients in a data file (of any format) and read them into fortran separately. If you really want to do it directly, one way is to write scripts to (1) correctly split the 120MB file into parts your compiler can handle, (2) wrap each part into a subroutine setting some elements of the argument, (3) generate code for a subroutine calling all other subroutines, and (4) compile all this into an object file. I would not use Fortran for these scripts.

Comment: @laxxy is there other way, for example, to save this data file as a prob.for and for example that this file is 10MB can I call it just, not divide on parts?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are taking a poorly chosen approach to solving this problem. As you say in one of your comments, you are generating these equations in matlab, and from there exporting these to fortran code - presumably because (possibly repeated) evaluation in matlab is too slow.

A much better approach would be to get matlab to generate the coefficients, and save these to disk in some portable form, e.g. [hdf5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) (a fast portable binary format which matlab and fortran can read and write). Then write some fortran code to import the coefficients into some arrays and use those arrays to calculate the required matrix elements.

Comment: Even a plain old ASCII file containing numbers and text would be better than OP's original plan.

Comment: @DaveP it is possible, but they are in connection, suppose that I already have matrices, I want to handle with them. What I can do?